# antlr grammar for comments, and plain text between tags

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Follow-up question to : [Getting plain text in antlr instead of tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365090/getting-plain-text-in-antlr-instead-of-tokens)

1.I used a rule

`COMMENT : START_1_TAG START_COMMENT END_1_TAG .*? START_2_TAG END_COMMENT END_2_TAG  -> skip;`

to skip any comments using my lexer.
But, I get a mismatched input , when I give any space inside the tags.

The part of my relevant part of my Lexer is:

```
lexer grammar DemoLexer;

START_1_TAG : '<%' -> pushMode(IN_TAG);
START_2_TAG : '<<' -> pushMode(IN_TAG);

COMMENT : START_1_TAG START_COMMENT END_1_TAG .*? START_2_TAG END_COMMENT END_2_TAG  -> skip;

TEXT        : ( ~[<] | '<' ~[<%] )+;

mode IN_TAG;
START_COMMENT : 'startcomment' ;
END_COMMENT : 'endcomment' ;
ID         : [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*;
INT_NUMBER : [0-9]+;
END_1_TAG  : '%>' -> popMode;
END_2_TAG  : '>>' -> popMode;
SPACE      : [ \t\r\n] -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

My issue is, `<%comment%>hi<%endcomment%>` gets parsed correctly. But, while I give my input as, `<% comment %>` or `<% endcomment %>`, with spaces in between the tags, it is not recognized by the COMMENT rule.

It gets recognized by the COMMENT rule, when I define the rule as:

`COMMENT : START_1_TAG SPACE*? 'commentstart' SPACE*? END_1_TAG .*? START_1_TAG SPACE*? 'commentend' SPACE*? END_1_TAG -> skip;`

with explicit spaces.

Is this the proper method to handle this?

2.I have a rule where I need the raw content inside a tag pair. 
Eg:

Here, the tokens need to be <%startraw%>,<%Hi%> and <%endraw%>

I tried using the text rule, but it dosen't work because it dosen't include '<%' and '<<'.

I tried:

in my parser,

```
rawText : RAW_TAG_START RAW_TEXT RAW_TAG_END ;
```

in my lexer,

```
RAW_TAG_START : '<%' 'startraw' '%>' -> pushMode(RAW_MODE);
RAW_TAG_END : '<%' 'endraw' '%>' -> popMode; 
mode RAW_MODE;
  RAW_TEXT : .*? ;
```

For some reason, when I try to parse this with the intellij antlr plugin, it seems to freeze and crash whenever I try to match the rawText rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the proper method to handle this?

No, I 'd say it's not. In this case, it's not just a plain comment, but it's a regular tag that happens to represent a comment. Therefor I'd treat it as any other tag (define it in the parser, not the lexer).

> For some reason, when I try to parse this with the intellij antlr plugin, it seems to freeze and crash whenever I try to match the rawText rule.

That could be because of this: `RAW_TEXT : .*? ;` that matches an empty string, and causes the lexer to produce infinite amount of tokens.

I would do something like this:

```antlr
lexer grammar DemoLexer;

START_1_TAG : '<%' -> pushMode(IN_TAG);
START_2_TAG : '<<' -> pushMode(IN_TAG);
TEXT        : ( ~[<] | '<' ~[<%] )+;

fragment S  : [ \t\r\n];
fragment ID : [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*;

mode IN_TAG;
  START_RAW     : 'raw' S* '%>' -> pushMode(IN_RAW);
  START_COMMENT : 'comment';
  END_COMMENT   : 'endcomment';
  END_ID        : 'end' ID;
  START_ID      : ID;
  INT_NUMBER    : [0-9]+;
  END_1_TAG     : '%>' -> popMode;
  END_2_TAG     : '>>' -> popMode;
  SPACE         : [ \t\r\n] -> channel(HIDDEN);

mode IN_RAW;
  END_RAW : '<%' S* 'endraw' S* '%>' -> popMode, popMode; // pop twice: out of IN_RAW and IN_TAG!
  ANY_RAW : . ; // No '+' or '*', just a single token!
```

A demo parser:

```antlr
parser grammar DemoParser;

options {
  tokenVocab=DemoLexer;
}

code
 : codeBlock* EOF
 ;

codeBlock
 : TEXT
 | tag1Ops
 | tag2Ops
 ;

tag1Ops
 : rawTag
 | commentTag
 | otherTag
 ;

rawTag
 : START_1_TAG START_RAW ANY_RAW* END_RAW
 ;

commentTag
 : START_1_TAG START_COMMENT END_1_TAG TEXT START_1_TAG END_COMMENT END_1_TAG
 ;

otherTag
 : START_1_TAG START_ID END_1_TAG TEXT START_1_TAG END_ID END_1_TAG
 ;

tag2Ops
 : START_2_TAG START_ID END_2_TAG TEXT START_2_TAG END_ID END_2_TAG
 ;
```

And a little main class to test it all:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String source = "aaa <% raw %> RAW <% endraw %> " +
            "bbb " +
            "<% foo %> FOO <% endfoo %> " +
            "ccc " +
            "<%comment%> COMMENT <%endcomment%> " +
            "ddd";

    DemoLexer lexer = new DemoLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
    DemoParser parser = new DemoParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    ParseTree tree = parser.code();

    System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));
  }
}
```

which will print:

```
(code
  (codeBlock aaa )
  (codeBlock (tag1Ops (rawTag <% raw %>   R A W   <% endraw %>)))
  (codeBlock  bbb )
  (codeBlock (tag1Ops (otherTag <% foo %>  FOO  <% endfoo %>)))
  (codeBlock  ccc )
  (codeBlock (tag1Ops (commentTag <% comment %>  COMMENT  <% endcomment %>)))
  (codeBlock  ddd)
  <EOF>)
```

*(I added some manual line breaks for clarity)*

And the ANTLR IntelliJ plugin can also cope with it:

[image]

### EDIT

If you're set on `skip`ping comments in the lexer (which I wouldn't do), then you could do something like this:

```antlr
lexer grammar DemoLexer;

COMMENT     : '<%' S* 'comment' S* '%>' .*? '<%' S* 'endcomment' S* '%>' -> skip;
START_1_TAG : '<%' -> pushMode(IN_TAG);
START_2_TAG : '<<' -> pushMode(IN_TAG);
TEXT        : ( ~[<] | '<' ~[<%] )+;
```

### EDIT II

If you've measured that `ANY_RAW` has a significant impact on performance, you could do something like this:

```antlr
mode IN_RAW;
  END_RAW  : '<%' S* 'endraw' S* '%>' -> popMode, popMode;
  SAFE_RAW : ( ~[<] | '<' ~[<%] )+

  // Fall through to match "<" from "<% ..." that are not matched by END_RAW
  OTHER_RAW  : . ;
```

Comment: The reason I tried to pass comments in the lexer is, it can include any content, including '<%' and any other tags. By defining it in the lexer, I can completely skip this line.
`<% commentstart %>
asdasdasdasdash
<%hi hello%>
<% commentend %>`

But in the changed grammar,I can't do this, since '<%' again gets parsed as tokens.

And regarding the raw, shouldn't the text content be a single token, instead of a multiple tokens?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the clarification.
I read in one of your previous answers to a question that, the '.' in a Lexer rule implies a single character, and a '.' in a Parser rule defines a token.
(or that is what I presumed from your answer). 

So, from my understanding, ANY_RAW rule matches any single character, or have I misunderstood something? 

`ANY_RAW : . ; // No '+' or '*', just a single token!`
and, from my previous comment, shouldn't the text content inside the raw tags be a single token, instead of a multiple tokens?

Comment: No, when the lexer is in the `IN_RAW` mode, it should match either the end of the raw-tag, or a single character (no matter what character it is). Then in you parser, you "glue" these `ANY_RAW` tokens (which are single characters) together. Note that when in raw-mode, the lexer always produces `ANY_RAW` tokens, so there's no need to do `.*?` or `.+?` in the parser. Simple doing `ANY_RAW*` in the parser works, as my example shows. Btw, what template language is this?

Comment: "[...] or have I misunderstood something?", no, you didn't misunderstand.

Comment: I was under the impression that having the content as a single token, would be more efficient than having it as a list of tokens.

It's something similar to Liquid. I have took some reference from your liqp repository too.

Comment: @john I wouldn't worry about performance (just yet), but check my **EDIT II**